# Is it possible to write html5 apps for android directly on a android device?

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to write html5 apps for android directly on a android device?

It seems like it should be possible since most files in a html5 app is ascii text, and those can be edited in place.
Or is there some limitations that would block this?

**Note1**: I did notice that both [vim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch) and [git](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.romanenco.gitt) is available, and there is usually a possibility to connect either usb or bluetooth keyboards, so it seems like some parts is there to create apps.

**Note2**: Since javascript is a script language and the interpreter is on the phone, is should possible to write html5 apps directly on the phone and then directly run them?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can see [phonegap](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=phonegap&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or [xdk](http://xdk-software.intel.com)

Comment: Can you really install those on a Android phone?

Comment: How? on xda there is some GNU/Linux install but I cant find a Android install.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure, but I will say that not. You need genereate apk with compiler, and this is only for Windows, Linux and MacOS.

Comment: But does a html5 app really need to be in a apk package?

Comment: You always need generate apk. This apk contains the permisions, the resources, icons... Other thing is that your make a "web" and the user open their browers and "entrer" in your web, but if you want a installable app, you need make a apk.

Comment: So not possible with a html5 android app, but maybe with basic html5 app.